# BulletedList in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How I can give separate style to custom image of Bulletdlist in .net?

Answer (score 0):

It could be done just by using CSS, for this you may check [this](http://www.tm4y.co.za/general-tips/css-bulleted-lists-styling.html) out.

To dynamically change any CSS attribute (C#.NET) do the following;

```
bulletedList.Style["cssProperty"] = "newValue";
```